# How to implement custom switch which looks same in all android versions

Tags: android

I have to use a switch which should look same in all android versions. The default switch available changes its appearance in different versions. Moreover I need the switch which should look like [image: this] with animation for sliding.

Comment: https://github.com/zcweng/ToggleButton  - try this

Answer (score 0):

Use -

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
            android:id="@+id/switch1"
            style="@style/ColorSwitchStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:checked="true"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:theme="@style/ColorSwitchStyle" />
```

It will be same from Android 2.1 (API level 7) and higher.

Edit:

```
 <style name="ColorSwitchStyle">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Add color of your choice

Comment: I have already tried this. I want the switch look exactly like I have shown in image.

Comment: @vishalgaurav Add style to the switch, have updated the answer

Comment: its coming default i.e magenta and the layout is also default.